# Blender 2.8 - What is 'Tweak' in Preferences > Keymap

Tags: shortcut

I've used Blender 2.7 for years, but I'm really trying to make an effort to figure out 2.8.

I was trying to randomize my vertices in edit mode; so I searched Preferences > Keymap for the shortcut to do this. Sure enough, it appeared as the following:

[image]

But what is tweak?? I'm guessing it's some hidden menu or something?? I've Googled for awhile, and cannot find anything about this.

TIA

Comment: I know it is about mouse movement with the left mouse button pressed in this case... but it would be nice to have a better explanation how to handle these parameters.

Answer (score 2):

*Tweak* is for when a mouse button needs to be pressed and held, followed by dragging the mouse. You can find this information in the docs of [Blender 2.8](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/keymap.html?highlight=tweak).

A good example for this is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd>. As long as you keep the right mouse button pressed, you can drag the 3D cursor around.

I couldn't find a particular purpose of having `transform.vertex_random` set to tweak, it doesn't seem to react to mouse drags. Perhaps that's a misconfiguration.

Comment: I had the exact same question as Codesmith. Furthermore, I tried to reassign Randomize to Ctrl Alt R but it just doesn't take. I can execute the command from the menu, but the shortcut does nothing. And it's not assigned to any other operation in Mesh Edit Mode. `transform.vertex_random` is the correct syntax according to the Info console. This is a mystery.